# Spring @value wtih calculation

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

I have a value stored in properties which is in minute unit
is it possible to convert it to second unit while using @value Annotation?
something like @Value("#{durationInMinutes*60}")?

Comment: Think it should work. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language ... why you dont try it ? ;)

Comment: Just found the solution: @Value("#{${durationInMinutes}*60*1000}")